# To extract and get some parts/clips out of a MP4 file to be concatenated into another

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

How to extract/get some parts/clips out of a MP4 file to be concatenated into another new MP4 file?

I tried to get/extract out only first 19 seconds, also a part beginning from 32th second up to its next 37 seconds, and finally part beginning from 2m29s up to its next 99 seconds, in this way:

```
$ ffmpeg -t 19 -i Example.mp4 -ss 0:0:32 -t 37 -i Example.mp4 -ss 0:2:29 -t 99 -i Example.mp4  -ss 0:0:0 -c copy ~/Downloads/ExampleOut.mp4
```

to no avail.

Please help me to get the correct one.

Comment: What do you get when you run that command?

Comment: See trim filter or concat demuxer as shown in each duplicate link.